# Does HIPAA apply to individuals?

Tags: privacy, hipaa

Does HIPAA privacy protection apply to an individual who has no relation to the healthcare field?

For example, my neighbor drops his prescription pill bottle on the sidewalk outside his house. I pick it up and return it. Would me telling someone else about his prescription be a HIPAA violation or just a jerk move?

Answer (score 22):

It would merely be a "jerk move".

HIPAA only applies to "covered entities":

1. Healthcare Providers
2. Health Plans
3. Healthcare Clearing Houses (i.e. Paying for your health care)
4. Business Associates of the Above)

Source: [CDC page on HIPAA](https://www.cdc.gov/phlp/publications/topic/hipaa.html)

Comment: Now, let's say you're a doctor in the same situation. Do you have to have a doctor-patient relationship for HIPAA to apply? Or would you be held to a higher standard as a healthcare provider anyway?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- A doctor, nurse, pharmacist or medical technician would all fall under "healthcare provider".

Comment: That isn't the question I asked.

Comment: Obviously, of course, it applies to individuals affiliated with "covered entities" and acting in that capacity.

Comment: @ohwilleke Talk of being "affiliated" with covered entities is misleading, I think. If "covered entities" were always organisations, instead of people, *then* I would agree with you, since actions done off the job and unrelated to one's work duties would unambiguously not be acts by any covered entity. But covered entities are *not* all organisations. Many professionals, such as doctors, *individually* count as "Health Care Providers" under HIPAA, and ergo they *personally* are "covered entities". It's not at all obvious to me they are freed from HIPAA obligations in non-work-related contexts.

Comment: @MarkAmery The kind of person I'm thinking of in terms of "affiliated" would be people like office staff and data entry contractors.